# AngularJS Uploading An Image With ng-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http, angularjs-fileupload

I am trying to upload a file in AngularJS using ng-upload but I am running into issues. My html looks like this:

```
<div class="create-article" ng-controller="PostCreateCtrl">
        <form ng-upload method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/write" >
            <fieldset>
                <label>Category</label>
                <select name="category_id" class="">
                    <option value="0">Select A Category</option>
                    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                        <option value="<?= $category -> category_id; ?>"><?= $category -> category_name; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>

                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="title span5" name="post_title"
                       placeholder="A catchy title here..."
                       value="<?= $post -> post_title; ?>" />

                <label>Attach Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="post_image" />

                 <a href='javascript:void(0)'  class="upload-submit: uploadPostImage(contents, completed)" >Crop Image</a>

                <label>Body</label>
                <div id="container">
                <textarea id="mytextarea" wrap="off" name="post_content" class="span7" placeholder="Content..."><?= $post -> post_content; ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div style='clear:both;'></div>
                <label>Preview</label>
                <div id='textarea-preview'></div>

            </fieldset>
            <div class="span7" style="margin: 0;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Create Post" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning pull-right draft" value="Save as Draft" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

And my js controller looks like this:

```
ClabborApp.controller("PostCreateCtrl", ['$scope', 'PostModel',
function($scope, PostModel) {

    $scope.uploadPostImage = function(contents, completed) {
        console.log(completed);
        alert(contents);
    }

}]);
```

The problem I am facing is when the crop image is hit and it executes uploadPostImage, it uploads the entire form. Not desired behavior but I can make it work. The big problem is in the js the function uploadPostImage 'contents' parameters is always undefined, even when the 'completed' parameter comes back as true.

The goal is to only upload an image for cropping. What am I doing wrong in this process?

Comment: Visit here for a simple image upload tutorial through angular.  It really helped me https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm

Comment: **Note** this question relates to the [ng-upload](https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload) library. Not the [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) library.

Answer (score 63):

There's little-no documentation on angular for uploading files. A lot of solutions require custom directives other dependencies (jquery in primis... just to upload a file...). After many tries I've found this with just angularjs (tested on v.1.0.6)

**html**

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"/>
```

Angularjs (1.0.6) not support *ng-model* on "input-file" tags so you have to do it in a "native-way" that pass the all (eventually) selected files from the user.

**controller**

```js
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("file", files[0]);

    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success( ...all right!... ).error( ..damn!... );

};
```

The cool part is the *undefined* content-type and the *transformRequest: angular.identity* that give at the $http the ability to choose the right "content-type" and  manage the boundary needed when handling multipart data.

Comment: Can I send some JSON data along with fd here. In fd I am always getting null, but files[0] is there. What is the problem

Comment: Are you using the code posted here? anyway about sending json data, actually didn't know yet :p it's better to post a new answer on this topic.

Comment: It's a really long long time until I've developed on php, anyway this has the same effect of build a form with a file "file" and then submitting at the 'uploadUrl' with a POST.

Comment: @StenMuchow sadly 'file' seems not support yet the binding with ng-change
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375

Comment: Every thing works fine, but I don't see the file on the server... Do the server need to do additional work? The PHP version sugested with $_FILES worked but I need an AngularJS solution!

Comment: This requires quite recent browsers because of the `FormData` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). It's certainly not supported by all the browsers which Angular test against...

Comment: The answer was given for AngularJS 1.0.6. is there something better now in Angular 1.2.26 or 1.3? The documentation still doesn't give any better ideas how to handle this.

Comment: i need to store the uploaded image to our app folders.... Can i know how it works....

Comment: @answer99 this code send data to a server through an HTTP POST method, it's the client side of a client-server communication. The server side has to react to this HTTP request and do what you want. I suggest to make a specific answer with details about what server you use.

Comment: Use `withCredentials: true,` only if you want to use cookies, then server would also need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`. Wasted lot of time being incautious. :)

Answer (score 19):

You can try [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) angularjs plugin (instead of [ng-upload](https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload)).

It's fairly easy to setup and deal with angularjs specifics. It also supports progress, cancel, drag and drop and is cross browser.

html

```
<!-- Note: MUST BE PLACED BEFORE angular.js-->
<script src="ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> 
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="ng-file-upload.min.js"></script> 

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="file" ngf-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//inject angular file upload directives and service.
angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var file = $files[i];
      $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'server/upload/url', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
        data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
        file: file,
      }).progress(function(evt) {
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
      }).then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  };
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case above mentioned methods work fine with php but when i try to upload files with these methods in node.js then i have some problem.
So instead of using $http({..,..,...}) use the normal jquery ajax.

For select file use this

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)"/>
```

And in controller

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(element) {   
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', $(element)[0].files[0]);
jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'brand/upload',
      type:'post',
      data: data,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      alert('Error uploading: ' + errorMessage);
      }
 });   
};
```

Comment: This answer uses jQuery instead of `ng-file-upload` or the AngularJS $http service.

Comment: @Tek Raj Pant Do you have any idea? how i give default image on above html part. I want to set by default one image so my button's on save work safely without onchange called or not

Answer (score 0):

```
        var app = angular.module('plunkr', [])
    app.controller('UploadController', function($scope, fileReader) {
        $scope.imageSrc = "";

        $scope.$on("fileProgress", function(e, progress) {
        $scope.progress = progress.loaded / progress.total;
        });
    });




    app.directive("ngFileSelect", function(fileReader, $timeout) {
        return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, el) {
            function getFile(file) {
            fileReader.readAsDataUrl(file, $scope)
                .then(function(result) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.ngModel = result;
                });
                });
            }

            el.bind("change", function(e) {
            var file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
            getFile(file);
            });
        }
        };
    });

    app.factory("fileReader", function($q, $log) {
    var onLoad = function(reader, deferred, scope) {
        return function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            deferred.resolve(reader.result);
        });
        };
    };

    var onError = function(reader, deferred, scope) {
        return function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            deferred.reject(reader.result);
        });
        };
    };

    var onProgress = function(reader, scope) {
        return function(event) {
        scope.$broadcast("fileProgress", {
            total: event.total,
            loaded: event.loaded
        });
        };
    };

    var getReader = function(deferred, scope) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = onLoad(reader, deferred, scope);
        reader.onerror = onError(reader, deferred, scope);
        reader.onprogress = onProgress(reader, scope);
        return reader;
    };

    var readAsDataURL = function(file, scope) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var reader = getReader(deferred, scope);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        readAsDataUrl: readAsDataURL
    };
    });



    *************** CSS ****************

    img{width:200px; height:200px;}

    ************** HTML ****************

    <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="UploadController ">
        <form>
        <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" ng-model="imageSrc">
                <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" ng-model="imageSrc2">
        <!--  <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple> -->
        </form>

        <img ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" />
    <img ng-src="{{imageSrc2}}" />

    </div>
    </div>
```