# How do I send a form from Angular to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I'm trying to send the data from my Angular form to a PHP file. I'm using Angular 4/5:

My TypeScript file:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    sendForm() {
       let formdata = document.querySelector('form');
       let datajson = {
           action: 'login', 
           username: formdata.username.value, 
           useremail: formdata.useremail.value,
           usersubject: formdata.usersubject.value,
           usermessage: formdata.usermessage.value
       };
       let apiurl = '../../assets/php/message.php';

       this.http.post(apiurl,datajson)
           .subscribe(data => {alert(datajson.data)})
          .catch(error => {alert (error.status)});
    }
}
```

The error:

```
error: core.js:1427 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of 
undefined at HTMLButtonElement.eval (home.component.ts:168) at 
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425) at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744) 
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424) at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192) at 
ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:499) at invokeTask (zone.js:1540) 
at HTMLButtonElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1566)
```

Comment: you should not use `document.querySelector` inside of angular apps. Better make use of `@ViewChild`

Comment: and what is your question? what is the error?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208082/angular-js-send-some-data-to-php-script

Comment: 'document.querySelector' is not the problem... I just want to send my data from the angular 4/5 form to PHP!

Comment: Pascal Allen: you link is about angular 1 or 2. I'm usign angular 4 and angular 5. So your link doesn't help...

Comment: Please edit your question and put the error message with the rest of the question instead of a comment. It's best that people can see the whole problem in the question and not have to read all the comments as well.

Comment: just as a comment... Seems you have a form, why not use either template driven form or reactive form. Just don't access DOM like that. Accessing DOM like that is everything what Angular is NOT about.

Answer (score 0):

You code needs to be inside a method, not global to the class.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    sendForm() {
        let formdata = document.querySelector('form');
        let datajson = {
           action: 'login', 
           username: formdata.username.value, 
           useremail: formdata.useremail.value,
           usersubject: formdata.usersubject.value,
            usermessage: formdata.usermessage.value
        };
        let apiurl = '../../assets/php/message.php';

        this.http.post(apiurl,datajson)
          .subscribe(data => {alert(datajson.data)})
          .catch(error => {alert (error.status)});
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and update your question with additional information, such as steps you have tried and error/problems you have found. It's hard to help when you only give us some of the information :-)

Comment: I'm just trying to send the data from my angular 4 form to a php file!!!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not calling `sendForm` the normal way, but rather in a callback not defined with the arrow function. So the `this` does not refer to the actual component, but to something else