# Can we submit a form multiple times without ajax

Tags: arrays, json, forms, coldfusion-9, submission

I have a JS array. Each element of that array is a form data in JSON format. I want to loop through this array and submit each form data to the server WITHOUT using AJAX. Can this be done? Any ideas would be a help.

Comment: So what is the issue? Put the data in a form field and submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I know is Using **Angualar JS** service [**$http**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
 $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'clone.php or servlet or other calls',
          data    : $scope.user, //forms user object
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
          .success(function(data) {
                    //do something
           });
```

References :

1. [Angularjs - simple form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985344/angularjs-simple-form-submit)
2. http://tutsnare.com/post-form-data-using-angularjs/

Comment: Angular js is not being used in the project. Anyways, the above code too will be like an AJAX request which I cant use

Answer (score 0):

I don't see if you mentioned where this is executing but if it's not client side (I'm assuming server side since this is tagged CF), you could `CFHTTP` each item by looping through the array.