# How to submit form to server in Angular2?

Tags: angular

Now the submission has been caught by angular2 even with action= in the <form>.

demo link: http://plnkr.co/edit/4wpTwN0iCPeublhNumT5?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <form action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" method="POST">
        <input name="q" value="test">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Comment: Posting a form directly causes a page reload, that's usually not what you want in an Angular application (SPA). Grab the data from the form and send an HTTP request from your code to the server instead.

Comment: With `target="_blank"` the post should be should to a new page. And the action actually point to a different domain, so xhr is not a option.

Comment: I see. You're right.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You should leverage the `NgSubmit` directive, as described below:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
  (...)
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.name"/>
  (...)
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

In this case, when you click on the submit button, the `onSubmit` method of the component will be called and you'll be able to manually send data to the server using the `HTTP` class on Angular2:

```
@Component({
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.data = {
      name: 'some name'
      (...)
    };
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.http.post('http://someurl', JSON.stringify(this.data))
        .subscribe(...);
  }
}
```

This way you can remain in the same page page.

**Edit**

Following your comment, you need to disable the behavior of the `NgForm` directive that catches the `submit` event and prevents it from being propagated. See this line: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L141.

To do that simply add the `ngNoForm` attribute to your form:

```
<form ngNoForm action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" method="POST">
  <input name="q" value="test">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

In this case, a new window will be opened for your form submission.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above. ngSubmit is not what I want. I just want to open a new window with post data.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your problem... You shoud use the `ngNoForm` attribute for your form. I updated my answer ;-)

Comment: Kudos!  I was running in to the same issue, where my form (wrapping a submit button to log out of my application) wasn't executing.  I spent an hour looking at my markup before it clicked that it might be an Angular2 specific thing.  Dropped in the ngNoForm attribute, and boom!  Success!  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier You should make some ng2 tutorials :)

Comment: `ngNoForm`, what an intuitive and logical annotation to add. But this just solved a problem I banged my head trying to get around for a week.

Comment: Submitting form in this way give the following error.
_Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.buyerzone.com/retail/atm-machines/rfqhp/?publisherId=myId&publisherTypeId=type&keywordID=' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource._

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
<form action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" method="POST" #form>
    <input name="q" value="test">
    <button type="submit" (click)="form.submit()">Search</button>
</form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Qjh8ooPpkfVgEe0dIv4q?p=preview

Comment: Hey this worked for me. Can you possibly add an explanation why? I just added the template variable and the click event

Comment: It's just how html forms work, when you submit them they'll send either a post or get request  as defined in the method attribute to the url defined in the action attribute

Answer (score 6):

You can also submit form in this way.

Here is HTML markup.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" #f="ngForm">
  (...)
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.name"/>
  (...)
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

And here is code in your **.ts file**.

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.target.submit();
  }
```

Comment: i appreciate this answer for not using ViewChild

Answer (score 2):

Hey if any one else ever has some annoying issue in Firefox when posting a form to a new url causes a page refresh and does not follow through to the page add `target="_parent"` and will fix the issue.