# How do I perform an actual form post within angular directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I know this sounds silly, but I am working on an angular 2 app and at some point in the workflow, I want to *submit* a `<form>` using the standard `POST` method.
**I do not want to call any AJAX or anything, I simply want to submit the form**.

```
<form action="http://server.com/address/to/submit" method="post">
    <input name="test" value="dummy" type="hidden">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I put the above code outside of any directive (so, in the `index.html`), the form submits as expected.

However, if the above code is inside a directive, it does not submit.

I understand that my angular application would be terminated at the time the user hits `submit`, but that is OK for my use case.

Comment: That was strange. I believe there must be some custom code that prevents it in your application. As you may see in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cC8GFjrn8i9zq1mwPeMI, the form is still able to be submitted.

Comment: Interesting! You are obviously correct, your plunker works. At this point, my app is pretty much straight-up angular 2 quickstart. Let me check what versions I am on, just in case it has updated.

Comment: Well, i'll be darn, I restarted the node server, got in and out of the developer tools in chrome and it now works! Well, problem solved, thanks!

Comment: No worries. I actually was on the other side that had to do extra work to keep the form from being submitted :)

Comment: And what did you do? because it's back to not submitting again. Frustrating.

Comment: Oh it depends on the button type. So if not specified or set to `type='submit'`, it should submit the form; if `type='button'` it should not. Another thing could prevent that default action is adding event to the button, then in your custom function call `preventDefault()` and `return false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120748/discussion-between-eric-liprandi-and-harry-ninh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to 2.0.0-rc.5, things were looking better. However, after enabling the `@angular/forms` module for another part of the app, it stopped submitting.
Turns out I need to use the `ngNoForm` directive/attribute as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34836908/80280).

The [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgForm-directive.html) is a bit obscure. If you look closely, the `selectors` lists `form:not([ngNoForm]):not([ngFormModel])`. I am not a jQuery expert, but this seems to indicate that this directive will **not** be applied to `form` elements that have a `ngNoForm` attribute.