# Navigate to particular component only after filling required input fields

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-forms

I have components called `demo`, demo component have 3 input fields and an button.Like this:

[image]

After clicking button(i,e submit) i am navigating to another component called `home`.This scenario is working fine for me, But i have added some validation for **first/last-name** and **email**.

If the user enters all the required input fields then only  it as to navigate to another component (i,e home).**But it is navigating without entering/validating the required input fields.**

While surfing i got some examples:

1) [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332343/angular-2-navigate-to-a-different-page-on-login)
2) [Example 2](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

But these are for `template-driven forms`. I am using reactive forms.

Here is the [Stakcblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-jbbmi8?file=app/demo/demo.component.html).

Comment: <button mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['../home']" type="submit" color="primary"  [disabled]="!addForm.valid" (click)="onaddCustomer()">Submit</button> .. should work ? i.e. you can disable the Submit button till the form is valid.

Comment: such losers closing nice questions... that has happened to me too. just ban these losers that close valid questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the button disabled since the form is valid

```
<button mat-raised-button  type="submit" color="primary" [disabled]="!addForm.valid"  (click)="onaddCustomer()">Submit</button>
```

and navigate in the click function

```
onaddCustomer(){

this.router.navigate(['/home']);

}
```

with out using `[disabled]`

check whether form valid or not in your click function

```
<button mat-raised-button  type="submit" color="primary"   (click)="onaddCustomer()">Submit</button>
```

and in click function

```
onaddCustomer(){

if(this.addForm.valid){
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
 }
```

Comment: your answer is working fine, but the button is in disabled state i want it to enabled state only( means color="primary").

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Now it's navigating to home (component) without entering any input fields.

Comment: Should i need to do any imports??

Comment: Getting this warning: (Proepert 'router' doesn't exist on type  'DemoComponent' any.)

Answer (score 2):

Simply disable the submit button till the form is valid, no other change is required.

Like that `[disabled]="!addForm.valid"`i.e. in your case:-

```
<button mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['../home']" type="submit" color="primary" [disabled]="!addForm.valid" (click)="onaddCustomer()">Submit</button>
```

OR

If you don't want to disable the button then remove `[routerLink]="['../home']"` from the button and in the component method add a condition for validation like:-

onaddCustomer(){

if (this.addForm.invalid) { return; }

this.router.navigate(['/home']);

}

Comment: your answer is working fine, but the button is in disabled state i want it to enabled state only( means color="primary").

Comment: Then just remove the [routerLink]="['../home']" from button and write it on component like:-                                                                     
                                                                                               onaddCustomer(){
// Stop if invalid
    if (this.addForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }

   this.router.navigate(['/home']);

}

Comment: See the edit in the answer.

Comment: Getting this warning: (Proepert 'router' doesn't exist on type  'DemoComponent' any.)

Answer (score 1):

Disabling just submit button may cause problems if you hit enter in an input as it submits the form. If you structured your form properly (as a reactive form), you could use a function on form submit.

```
<form [formGroup]="yourReactiveFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  ...
</form>
```

and in `onSubmit()` function:

```
onSubmit() {

    // Stop if invalid
    if (this.yourReactiveFormGroup.invalid) {
        return;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/your-route']);
}
```