# Export input value Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

In Angular 6, I have the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss'],
})

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    formulario: FormGroup

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
            pesquisa: [null],
        })
    }
    teste() {
        console.log(this.formulario.value.pesquisa)
    }
}
```

How can I export the "this.formulario" so that I can use it in a service?

I am capturing the data entered in an input via ngSubmit and I want to pass it to the url of an API (which is defined in a service).

I am a beginner and I do not find solutions clear enough for my understanding.

Comment: in Angular, components should inject services. So you can call a service passing your form on your submit: `onSubmit() { this.myService.method(this.formulario); }`

Comment: see https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectable-and-nested-service-dependencies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit form to server in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835516/how-to-submit-form-to-server-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first inject your `service` inside your `component`. So that you can call your `service` `method` from the component with your `form data` as input. This is the recommended way to pass `form data` to the server. From your service, you can extract all the form data and build a request object. Or else you extract inside component and pass it to service for api calls.

Sample code :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss'],
    providers : [AppService]
})

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    formulario: FormGroup

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _appService : AppService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
            pesquisa: [null],
        })
    }
    teste() {
       // You can also extract form data inside component itself and then prepare object to pass it to service
       let myData = {
         name : this.formulario.value.userName,
         firstName : this.formulario.value.firstName
       }
        this._appService.saveData(myData);
        console.log(this.formulario.value.pesquisa)
    }
}
```