# TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm getting the following error in Chrome console,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
```

Here is my javascript function,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var formApp = angular.module('formApp',[]);

    function formController($scope,$http){
        $scope.formData = {};

        $scope.processForm = function(){
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/ABCAPI/v1/image/front',
                data : $.param($scope.formData.imageFile),
                headers : {'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data" , 'Auth-Token' : "X"}
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log("");

                if (!data.success) {
                    // if not successful, bind errors to error variables

                } else {
                    // if successful, bind success message to message
                    $scope.message = data.message;
                }
            })
        };
    }

</script>
```

What does above error means and where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the error originates from the presented code?

Comment: The only jQuery you have in the sample is `$.param`, and nothing directly reads any `jquery` property there, so it seems a bit unlikely.

Comment: My bad, just noticed that `$.param(undefined)` throws your reported error. See answer below.

Comment: indeed, confused about the message i'm getting. any idea about the reason for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$scope.formData.imageFile` seems to evaluate to `undefined`.

```
$.param(undefined) //throws Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
```

Do a `console.log($scope.formData)` right before the `$http()` call. The `$scope.formData` object most likely does not contain an `imageFile` property, or `imageFile` is `null`/`undefined`.

Note that [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) takes a plain object or array as the first argument, providing another type of value (or no value) falls under undefined behavior.

---

Also, if I'm reading your code correctly, you're trying to upload an image file through `$http`. It won't work that way, you need XHR2's [`FormData` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504984/1331430) for a simple implementation.

Angular does not support `ng-model` on `<input type="file">`, which is the reason for the former error.

Comment: @dystroy yes, though `$.param(undefined)` is pretty much equivalent to `$.param()` (no arguments), and `$.param` has no documented zero-arguments signature. So it falls under undefined behavior, I guess.

Comment: It might also be argued that we don't want jQuery to be overloaded with code only designed to let errors make sense. In any case, have an upvote for your diagnostic.

Comment: Yes, with error call stack and breakpoints we can solve these issues rather quickly nowadays.