# AngularJs use object in post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a json object to my `factory.login` method so I can re use it.

This is my code:

**Controller function**

```
var data = {email:'test','password':'test'};

vm.login = function() {
            employeeFactory.login(vm.url, vm.data)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }, function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data.status);
                    });
        }
```

**Factory**

```
factory.login = function(url,data) {
        return $http({
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': url,
            'data': $.param(
                data
            ),
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
    }
    return factory;
```

But the error is:

```
angular.js:13294 TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
    at Function.n.param (jquery-2.2.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.factory.login (employeeFactory.js:14)
    at employeeController.vm.login (employeeController.js:16)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (angular.js:14138), <anonymous>:4:285)
    at b (angular.js:15151)
    at e (angular.js:24674)
    at m.$eval (angular.js:16895)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:16995)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:24679)
    at HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery-2.2.2.min.js:3)
```

Comment: seems like you have a problem with injecting jquery to your code.  are you minimizing your code?

Comment: well!!!! don't get this wrong....What is the question?

Comment: No I've not minimized it.

Comment: also in your html make sure script tag for jquery comes before angularjs

Comment: Jquery comes first. That's not the problem.

Comment: You can try this too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255195/convert-param-in-angularjs

Comment: As per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150139/typeerror-cannot-read-property-jquery-of-undefined), which is basically identical, $.param is probably the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

This should be `vm.data`

```
vm.data = {email:'test','password':'test'};
```

And factory doesn't require jQuery at all, just use below construction

```
factory.login = function(url,data) {
    return $http({
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': url,
         //don't use $.param, as you need jQuery dependency for that
         //for x-www-form-urlencoded you have to use this construction
         //email=test&password=test
        'data': 'email=' + data.email + '&password=' + data.password, 
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
}
return factory;
```

But consider using JSON type on server request handler, as it's much easier

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON seems incorrect. Should be:

`var data = { "email": "test", "password": "test"};`

Also the `$http.post` function is available:

`$http.post(url, data, [{headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}]);`

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a format to serialize object, so it's a string.
You have your object as data that contains the data to be sent to the server, so just do this:

Just put your data object in it:

```
factory.login = function(url,data) {
    return $http({
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': url,
        'data': data
    });
}
return factory;
```

Angular will send json to the server in the payload. You don't need to do that serialization your self.

Documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
-> Default Transformations ->

> Request transformations ($httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest and
>   $http.defaults.transformRequest):
>
> If the data property of the request configuration object contains an
>   object, serialize it into JSON format. Response transformations
>   ($httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse and
>   $http.defaults.transformResponse):
>
> If XSRF prefix is detected, strip it (see Security Considerations
>   section below). If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a
>   JSON parser.

The stack trace show the following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

miss match variable uses declared `var data = {}` but used `vm.data` in your controller. should declare as

`vm.data= {email:'test','password':'test'}`

or

use `data` in `employeeFactory.login(vm.url, data)` if declare as `var data= {}`

and in your factory no need to use `$.param` can send as argument in post method like

```
$http.post(url, data, [{headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}]);
```

[Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)